# Android - Preserve array value while moving to and returning from the another activity

Tags: android

I am having 2 activities:

1st Activity contains 2 arrays which are filled up with the data by making call to a webservice. And both the arrays are used to display data in ListView. On clicking on any List Item, i am opening new activity Activity-2, here i am posting data related with that selected List-item.

But i am facing trouble **when i return from Activity-2 to Activity-1 , it agains goes to fetch data from Webservice into Array(Instead of, It should go for fetching data if there is anything posted from 2nd activity otherwise it should get preserved arrays value). So my question is how do i preserve value of both the arrays so that i remains preserve the same value. so it does not have to go for fetching again and again.**

(I think i need to use the "Save activity state" kind of concept, but i didnt have implemented such concept yet, so please if you know such then pls let me know for the same.)

### Update:

I have added "(Instead of, It should go for fetching data if there is anything posted from 2nd activity otherwise it should get preserved arrays value)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put them the values you retrieved in the `Bundle` passed to `onSaveInstanceState`:

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Put your values into outState
    outState.putStringArray("my.project.str.array", stringArray);
    outState.putStringArrayList("my.proj.str.array.list", strArrayList);

    // read the documentation on Bundles to see complete 
    //      list of values you can put in

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

And then you can retrieve them back via `onRestoreInstanceState`.

**EDIT**: You can put in more than one string array or string array list or whatever value, as long as the keys are different for each.

Comment: thanx for the support, but can you please let me know that how do i store 2 arrays ? what if i am having more than 2 two arrays ?

Comment: You can put in two or even more arrays.  I will edit my answer to illustrate. Btw, I also answered your question on the progress dialog. Please give feedback also. Thanks.

Comment: i am apologizing for that, will sure give feedback after the implementation of your concept

Comment: you are right about storing array, but can you show me a way for "When i posted date from 2nd activity,then it should go for fetching data instead of taking preserved array values"?

Comment: Wait, so your flow is Activity 1 -> Activity 2 -> Activity 1 right?  When going from Activity 2 to Activity 1, do you want to get the "old" values or fetch again from the webservice? I thought you wanted the "old" values, but from your comment, it looks like you want new values.